# phaser.text up down without angle

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

How to make phaser.text label to go upwards/downwards without angle that causes fonts to turn, without adding linefeed after each letter, I want to output something like this easily with one text label/string:

```
C 
A 
T
```

Comment: You want `<label>CAT</label>` to print like your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, there's no built-in support for something like this, but it's easy enough to add the linefeeds programmatically.

```
let text = this.game.add.text(0, 0, "CAT", { fill: 'white' });
let oldLabel = text.text;

text.text = '';

for (let i = 0; i <= oldLabel.length; i++) {
    text.text += oldLabel[i] + '\n';
}
```